# What is the best way to mount files generated by one pod on another pod (before it starts) on a different node in GCP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, volumes

I have a simple use case. I am trying to deploy two pods on two different nodes in Kubernetes. `Pod A` is a server which creates a file `abc.txt` after receiving an API request. I want to mount this `abc.txt` file onto `Pod B`.

If the file `jhsdiak.conf` (the name of this file is randomly generated) is not present on `pod B` before it starts, `pod B` will create its own default file. Hence to avoid this, the file has to be mounted onto `Pod B` before it starts.

Here are the things I have tried

- Shared Volume using dynamically provisioned PVC -> This approach works fine if both the pods are created on the same node. Not otherwise as GCP doesn't support ReadWriteMany.
- Using Kubectl CP to copy the files from `Pod A` to host path and then creating configmaps/secrets to mount it onto `Pod B` -> This approach fails as the name of file jhsdiak.conf is randomly generated.
- InitContainers -> I am not sure how I can use an init container to move files from one pod to another.
- Using NFS Persisted storage -> I haven't tried it yet, but seems like a lot of overhead to just move one file between pods.

Is there a better or more efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Seems like NFS/Cloud Filestore is [the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535535/storage-readwritemany-in-google-kubernetes-engine).

Comment: What the file size? How many do you have per day?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Files are root certificates. So very minute. And I just have ten files in total. Not per day, but just once at the beginning.

Comment: @char I did consider NFS/Cloud Filestore, but it seems like a lot of overhead. I can choose that option but I just need to confirm that it is the right way to go.

Comment: Whatever you do, dont use NFS, the overhead is terrible.
You can use a storageClass but you will have to implement your own mechanism for access control or otherwise you might endup with two random files instead of one

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution is to use Cloud Storage for storing your files.

But, I have another solution than "file". Create a PubSub topic and push your files in it with `Pod A`.
Create a pull subscription and poll it with `Pod B`.

You can achieve what you want, I mean sending data from A to B, and you don't have to worry about file system.

If your cluster is compliant with Knative, the eventing solution can help you for staying inside the cluster (if it's a requirement)